# Create API Mapping with Cloudformation and Api Gateway V1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created an AWS Api Gateway (edge optimized) with CloudFormation. So far, everything works great. Now I´d like to make that API available under a custom domain, so I also added a [custom domain resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html) to my CFN scripts. However, I do not see any possibility to also create an API mapping with CFN. If I create that manually, everything works fine, but I want do have it as part of the CFN scripts. I´ve seen in the documentation, that there is an [ApiMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-apimapping.html) available for Api Gateway v2 resources, but as per my understanding this does not work with edge optimized APIs. Can you help me here?

Kind regards

Comment: What is your CFN template and where is the issue with it?

Comment: You need a [BasePathMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-basepathmapping.html) resource to map a custom domain to a "v1" REST api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BasePathMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-basepathmapping.html) indeed did the trick. That was not that obvious in my opinion, since the documentation nowhere states the purpose of that resource. Thank you.

Comment: May be worth noting that API Gateway V1 doesn't support the slash character (/) in base path mappings. To create a multi-level base path mapping (_e.g._ `v0/users`), we need to use API Gateway V2.